# Geometric means of even/odd complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-geometry

I would like to know if there exists a geometric mean beyond the even/odd complex functions. Here the definitions I know.

Let

$\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be a nonempty subset of complex field such that
 $$z\in\Omega\iff -z\in\Omega;$$

$f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ be a complex function over $\Omega$.

We say that $f$ is an even function over $\Omega$ if and only if $$f(-z)=f(z)$$ while $f$ is an odd function over $\Omega$ if and only if $$f(-z)=-f(z).$$

Maybe this is a silly question, I'm studying Complex Analysis on my own.

Comment: Did you ask for symmetries, as in discrete groups, and the functions invariant under the action of a discrete group? $\{-1,1\}$ with multiplication is a discrete group, $(a_g(f))(z)=g^n·f(gz)$ is a group action, the even and odd functions are the invariants. You can take the groups of unit roots, ... to define similar invariant functions.

Answer (score 0):

By the geometric mean of two, three, or n complex numbers (or, if you prefer, functions), I presume you mean (uv)^(1/2),  (uvw)^(1/3), and so on, which would certainly seem to exist.  Perhaps, in the case of functions, you are afraid of the annihilator, which at times seems to threaten even my own existence.

For well behaved complex functions, (functions that do not annihilate their neighbors), I see no reason why a geometric mean could not be defined.

Methods from functional analysis could perhaps be used for polynomials and other infinite dimensional functions.  See if you can't come up with an appropriate norm.  Best wishes!